# extjs with xtemplate values and conditions - basic

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I want to use xtemplate and to condition the text that will appear.
im trying:

```
<tpl for=".">;
<tpl if="data1=="something"">;
    'something will appear here<tpl>';
<tpl elseif="data2="somethingelse"">;
    'something else </tpl>;
</tpl>
```

BUt its not working
whats wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to escape quotes in your if statement:

```
<tpl  if="data1=="something"">
```

should be

```
<tpl if="data1==\"something\"">
```

also they need to be comma seperated strings, just like in the examples

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.  However, what worked for me was specifically using single quotes (and escaping them), rather than double quotes:

```
<tpl elseif="data2 == \'somethingelse\'">,
'something else',
'</tpl>'
```